# Implementing a tutorial/introduction for a web application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am looking for a library or some information on how to build an introduction to a website. These days you often find websites that offer an introduction to the different functions that the website offers. Usually it is a tutorial that darkens the entire page except some parts in a step by step fashion. These parts then are labeled with an explanation and the other darkened part of the website is not accessible for the duration of the introduction.

It is really hard to find information on this because of the key words 'tutorial' or 'introduction' which will usually lead you to tutorials of the searched framework or programming language.

I am programming in React so I would like to know resources that would help me or many a library that I can use for something like that. Even key words or a common name for this would help me already.

Comment: Maybe this: https://introjs.com/

Comment: Here's one I've been using: http://bootstraptour.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple one developed by LinkedIn. There's not a lot of free ones out there as I recently went down this path. I ended up using Hopscotch. It's got some pro/cons but ultimately it's easy to use and get's the job done. On the con side, it's not responsive.

http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out. Is there a general name for this feature?

Comment: Oooh this one is pretty!

Comment: Nope. That was my top difficulty. I had no idea what they were called and therefore made it difficult to search for.

Comment: @mwilson It looks like the term 'tour' is often used in this context.

Comment: @Goldi. Yea, tour will yield the most results. I believe that's how I landed on hopscotch. Their main object that you work with is a 'tour'